# Says hashed password is incorrect but they are the same

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to learn a secure login so i was looking up tutorials. I found [this](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) tutorial useful and got a registration page working perfectly but the login keeps returning wrong password. 
This means its getting the username but is going wrong somewhere.

Any idea how i can fix this, whether you see the error or know of a way i can fix it?

Any help is appreciated

```
// Check if username is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
} else{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}

// Check if password is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
    $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}

// Validate credentials
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                        save the username to the session */
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                        header("location: welcome.php");
                    } else{
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                    }
                }
            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: did you follow that tutorial *exactly* and did all the steps? or did you leave out anything you thought you'd do on your own and figured it'd be ok?

Comment: Followed all the steps, got the registration working and entering the database then links to login, enter the username just made and password but gives the error when password is invalid. That must mean the username was found in the database.

Comment: any spurious blank spaces at the end of the hashed password perhaps?

Comment: what does a var_dump() on the hash produce? also, use `mysqli_error($link)`  and error reporting, see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Nope, have it set to trim as well.

Comment: I've not seen in your code where $hashed_password has been defined

Comment: @hanslutterf. that's done here `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);`

Comment: @J.Finlay I've stayed in here long enough and haven't seen a response from what I asked for you to do. If you have any error messages or need more help, ping me back or others. I have now left the question, good luck.

Comment: I think the problem is here : if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){ ...  This value $hashed_password has to be that in the database

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner. honestly, im not very good at this and im still trying to do what you asked

Comment: @hanslutterf. the hashed password in the database is saved under password but that shouldnt make a difference?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner its returning NULL for the var_dump()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my password in my database from varchar(50) to varchar(100). I did this because the hash made the password too big for what i was storing.

Comment: Good. I've also made such an error before